# How to remove script spam from wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, spam

this appears in the head of my webpage and displays pop-up adds how to remove this scripts, I can't finde this scripts in web files.These scripts don't have path..
[enter link description here](http://prntscr.com/fav6kr)

Answer (score 1):

did you check header.php in current theme? or you can de activate current theme and activate wordpress default theme to check if there is some thing wrong with current theme. Same for plugins you can de activate one by one to see if problem is fixed and then activate again.